# Oracle SQL Developer said my procedure is modified outside JDeveloper

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got this message when I'm editing a procedure in Oracle 11g

[image]

Actually I'm the only one who is editing the procedure. Sometimes when I'm coding, it prompts, I accidentally press space bar and it loads the last saved codes. This happened a few times. I got mad.

Why does this message prompt even I'm the only one who edits this procedure? Is this related to the setting of my SQL developer? The version I'm using is 4.0.3.

Comment: Am I the only one having this problem?

Comment: I just lost a day's work because of this. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I get this error a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is caused by the client and db server time being off.

"We're checking the time in the db to see when the last time it was modified and comparing it to your local time. Can you confirm your db and local times are correct?"
That Jeff Smith (SQL Developer Team Lead or something)

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3513778?tstart=0

Comment: I run "select sysdate from dual;" and compared the time with my local computer, the difference is about 10 seconds. Does it matter?

Comment: I would recommend using the lastest sql developer.  If you still get the error with a 10 second time difference, then sync the server and client time.  Most likely the new version of sql developer doesn't get this error